# PayPal SDK and Android integration issue

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I'm making a small app that will allow users to pay for things like coffee etc with paypal. Getting started I set up a developer account, got all my credentials and followed the documentation to set up. 
Then I started with the sample app that paypal provided to see that it works. I click Pay and I get the paypal login page fine. No apparent problems. But the login button and the sandbox button are greyed out, allowing me to do nothing.

What could be causing this?

I am based in Ireland, so is this the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ruffles - Until a valid email and some password is entered, the login button is not enabled for clicking.  Also, the sandbox display is not a button, it is just an indicator that you are communicating with the PayPal sandbox and not the production environment.